# Oracle EBS R12 - Form Personalization - Disable a particular field

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-ebs

User should not update the `Ordered Quantity Fields` in the tabs ie (`Pricing ,Shipping,Addresses,Returns,Service,Others`) if it satisfies a certain condition.
 If someone tries to update - just pop-up an error message

> "Update not allowed here !!"

I think we can achieve this using Form Personalization.
But I am not sure actually (`Trigger Event,Trigger Object,Condition`) - how to disable particular field

Kindly Help.
Let me know if you need any more inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your condition, if it depends on record data, if it can change when user changes data, etc.

If the condition is constant during forms session, use `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger like this

```
if _condition_ then
    set_item_property('your_block.item1', UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
    set_item_property('your_block.item2', UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
    ...
end if;
```

if your condition depends on record data, use `POST-QUERY` trigger in similar way

```
if _condition_ then
    set_item_instance_property('your_block.item1', :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD, UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
    set_item_instance_property('your_block.item2', :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD, UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
    ...
else
    set_item_instance_property('your_block.item1', :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD, UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_TRUE);
    set_item_instance_property('your_block.item2', :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_RECORD, UPDATE_ALLOWED, PROPERTY_TRUE);
    ...
end if;
```

if your condition depends on record data, which can user modify use additional `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` trigger whith the same code as the `POST-QUERY-TRIGGER`